# Custom animation for toolbar's action mode

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-actionmode

When I call `toolbar.startActionMode(...)` it defaultly see a fade animation, I would like to change that to a slide animation. As I can just touch the `Toolbar` view directly, I don't know how to do this.

I can do this by using 2 toolbars and just animate the second one. But as the `Toolbar` provides an action mode and I already use it, I would like to know if I somehow can modify it's animation...

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't give you access to the ActionMode "toolbar". Which by the way is not a `Toolbar`. The type of the context "toolbar" is `ActionBarContextView`.

If you want full control you need to implement your own Action Mode with 2 toolbars. Then u can add the animation you desire.